# Регулярные выражения для ФИО и для Инициалов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Получаю строку

```
 '<div class="authors">Редактор: <a href="/authors/111070/">Цветкова Т. В.</a></div>'
```

или `'<div class="authors">Редактор: <a href="/authors/111070/">Федоров-Немов Владимир Иванович</a></div>'`

или `'<div class="authors">Редактор: <a href="/authors/111070/">Федоров-Немов В.</a></div>'`

фамилии могу быть разные, как мне написать регулярку, чтобы брать из строки ФИО или инициалы?

Фамилия всегда начинается с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Парсить HTML регулярными выражениями – весьма плохая идея. Для парсинга HTML существуют специально предназначенные для этого средства.

Но если Вы уж так хотите, то самый примитивный вариант:

```
\/">(.*)<\/a
```

Проверить можно [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/Sj2E8s/1).

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а можно уточнить для этого случая '<div class="authors">Автор: <a href="/authors/176417/">Лаврова Любовь Николаевна</a>, <a href="/authors/176418/">Чеботарева Ирина Васильевна</a></div>'

Comment: @shatoidil, Нужно только первое ФИО или оба?

Comment: Сделал вот так \ /">(.*?)<\ /a и помогло вроде, да нужно две фамилии взять. Правильно же сделал?

Comment: @shatoidil, Да, можно и так.

Answer (score 1):

По вашему примеру можно так:

```
/\/">(\D+)\ (\D+)\ (\D+)<\/a/
```

Или вот так:

```
/\/">([А-Яа-я-.]+)\ ([А-Яа-я-.]+)\ ([А-Яа-я-.]+)<\/a/
```